# What does "RUNNINGAS=`/usr/bin/id -un`" do?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

What does "RUNNINGAS=`/usr/bin/id -un`" do?

Comment: Questions asking for a link to a resource are off-topic here, which is why I've removed that from the question. That said, the [Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) or the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) are good resources; avoid the ABS, which tends to demonstrate bad practices.

Comment: Thank you Charles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the help ;)

```
 ❯ id --help                                                                                                           [16:52:24]
Utilisation : id [OPTION]... [UTILIS]
Afficher les informations d'utilisateur et de groupe de l’UTILISateur indiqué,
ou pour l'utilisateur actuel quand UTILIS est omis.

  -a             ignorée, pour compatibilité avec les autres versions
  -Z, --context  n'afficher que le contexte de sécurité du processus
  -g, --group    n'afficher que le GID effectif
  -G, --groups   afficher tous les GID
  -n, --name     afficher le nom au lieu du numéro, pour -ugG
  -r, --real     afficher l'identifiant réel au lieu de l'effectif, avec -ugG
  -u, --user     n'afficher que l'UID effectif
  -z, --zero     délimiter la sortie avec des caractères NULL au lieu de blancs ;
                   impossible avec le format par défaut
      --help     afficher l'aide et quitter
      --version  afficher des informations de version et quitter

Sans aucune OPTION, afficher des informations utiles d'identification.

Aide en ligne de GNU coreutils : <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Signalez les problèmes de traduction de « id » à : <traduc@traduc.org>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/id>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) id invocation'
```

Every user has :

- a username
- a user ID

  - UID = 0 for root
  - UID >= 1000 for real users usually
- a group ID
- a list of groups and their IDs : `sudo, users, disk, lock, uucp,…`

Here :

- `id` shows user info.
- `-u` only shows info for the current user
- `-n` does not show the UID (user ID)

**So finally you got… The username !**

The reverse quotes ``   allow to set the variable `RUNNINGAS` to what the command returns.

Answer (score 1):

It sets the shell variable `RUNNINGAS` equal to the output of the command `/usr/bin/id -un`.  On most systems, this would be your username.  Note that since, as far as we can tell here, `RUNNINGAS` has not been `export`ed, the value of the variable would not be available to subshells started from this shell.

You can use `man` to get information on the `id` command (`man id`).  Most other commands also have manpages, which are a good resource for learning what the commands are for and how to use them and their various options.

Comment: I'd suggest saying "output of" rather than "result of" -- after all, the exit status could also be considered a result, but isn't being assigned here.

Comment: It's also worth distinguishing that this is a shell variable, as opposed to an environment variable. (A *poorly-named* shell variable, inasmuch as it disregards POSIX naming conventions specifying all-caps names for variables with meaning to the system or shell and reserving names containing lowercase characters for application use).

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other way or command to check the username?

Comment: `whoami` would also display your current username.

Comment: @SGR29, per [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), `"$USER"` also expands to the current username.